# How to escape $ in Visual Studio Code snippet creation

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets

It seems when using PHP variables like $_SERVER the code snippet ignores the $. For example

```
{
// Example:
"IP Address Test": {
    "scope": "php",
    "prefix": "iptest",
    "body": [
                "// Debugging",
                "if($_SERVER[\"REMOTE_ADDR\"]=='${1:ipaddress}'){",
                "\t//run only my ip",
                "\t$0",
                "}"
    ],
    "description": "Test only from IP address"
}
```

}

outputs :

```
// Debugging
if(_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]=='xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'){
//run only my ip

}
```

Comment: Double back-slashes `\\$` is probably the right way to do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't use \ you have to use double $ ..

eg.

```
// Debugging
if($$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]=='xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'){
    //run only my ip

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't add a comment, but Mark has the correct answer.

$$ places the cursor at the beginning of the $ once VSCode has rendered the string. \ correctly places the cursor where you want it instead of one at every $. So, instead of...

```
<--cursor-here-->$_SERVER
```

// before $ gives us

```
$_SERVER<--cursor-here-->
```